# Force HTTPS too many redirect with .htaccess, how to resolve?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I know this has been asked and answered several times and I have gone through a lot of them but still have not solved my issue.

I have the following code in my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I want to redirect all of the following:

- `http://www.example.com`
- `http://example.com`
- `https://example.com`

to redirect to `https://www.example.com`.

Currently it comes up to an error page stating too many redirects, I have tried clearing cookies to no avail.

What am I doing wrong and how can I make it work?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This canonicalises both the HTTPS and www subdomain in a single rewrite. Basically, this says... For all requests that are not HTTPS *OR* where the hostname does not start `www` then redirect to `https://www.example.com/<whatever>`.

The `%1` backreference holds the hostname, less the optional `www` subdomain, from the preceding *CondPattern* that is always matched.

You need to use the server variable `HTTPS` (ie. `%{HTTPS}`), not the environment variable `HTTPS` (ie. `%{ENV:HTTPS}`).

Comment: Hi DocRoot, thanks for your reply, unfortunately even after using the following code, it results with the error page, stating too many redirects.

Comment: How is your SSL cert implemented? For instance, are you are behind an SSL proxy, like Cloudflare's Flexible SSL service?

Comment: Hi, the issue appears to be resolved now, I think the redirect loop was coming from another redirect I had set up with my hosting provider, on their cPanel. Thanks for the answer :)